# Were Christoffel symbols used by Riemann?

Tags: biographical-details, relativity-theory, differential-geometry

The answer to the question would appear to be "no" looking at the transcription of Riemann's 1854 [Ueber die Hypothesen, welche der Geometrie zu Grunde liegen](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Riemann/Geom/WKCGeom.html) lecture. However, Bernhard Riemann (1826-1866) and Elwin Bruno Christoffel (1829–1900) were contemporaries.

Is there any manuscript in which Riemann adopted the use of Christoffel symbols?

Comment: [Christoffel introduced his symbols in 1869](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN243919689_0070?tify=%7B%22pages%22:[50],%22view%22:%22info%22%7D), Riemann died in 1866, so no.

Comment: See my question at https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7974/notation-for-christoffel-symbols.  In short, Christoffel himself did not even use "his" symbols $\Gamma_{ij}^k$. They were introduced much later by Einstein in his work on general relativity.