# Einstein's contribution to Mathematics?

Tags: mathematics-social-history

What contribution to mathematics did Einstein make, or was he only interested in Physics and derived formulas using mathematics?

Comment: Einstein summation convention? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation

Comment: He devised a new proof of the Pythagorean Theorem.

Comment: The $\Gamma^i_{jk}$ notation for Christoffel symbols. See https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7974/notation-for-christoffel-symbols

Comment: His work in physics also directly inspired mathematical interest in Lorentzian manifolds, and more generally semi-Riemannian manifolds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a discussion of Einstein's early and late views on mathematics at https://www.quora.com/Why-did-Einstein-write-Since-the-mathematicians-have-invaded-the-theory-of-relativity-I-do-not-understand-it-myself-anymore-After-all-GR-relies-heavily-on-mathematics. Although he had been taught by Minkowski at ETH Zurich, he apparently had no relationship with him and disliked his approach to spacetime in special relativity. When he subsequently exploited this in general relativity, he is said to have acknowledged his debt.

Comment: Thank you sir @Tony Solomonides